# Search for a candidate function with specific properties?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, inequality

Given the following expression:
$$ \mathcal{F(p,c,r,s)} = \frac{c^2 p^2 \left(s f'(s)-2 f(s)\right)^2}{4 f(s) \left(c^2 f(s) \left(c^2 p^2 f(s)+s^2 \left(r^2-p^2\right)\right)+\left(-r^2-1\right) s^4\right)} $$

where $s$ is a variable on the range $0<s<1$, furthermore $r,~c$ and $p$ are some parameters and $f(s)$ is an arbitrary function (note that its first derivative is also involved), how can a candidate function $f(s)$ be found such that $f(1)=1$ and $0<\lim_{p\to 0}\mathcal{F(p,c,r,s)}<\infty$ is regular for all $0<s<1$ (neglecting the boundaries since they are points of zero measure)?
Also, is it possible to construct such a function, where additionally $\mathcal{F(p,c,r,1)}\equiv0$ only at the right boundary $s=1$?

Comment: Despite your throwing in at the end "How would one go about solving it in Mathematica?", this strikes me as a general math problem as it is currently stated. If you were to come up an algorithm and ask for help in implementing it, I could see it relevant to _Mathematica_.SE,